# Saving web pages to NTFS partition corrupts those files and folder in Windows

Tags: windows, ntfs

When saving a complete web page in Firefox, Chrome etc. (where a file and a folder containing many files is created), to an NTFS partition, those files and that folder become corrupt and reported as damaged in Windows.

A Windows `chkdsk` is required to fix it (and delete the offending files).

Saving single files does not seem to cause problems.

This was a problem years ago and has recently happened to me again. Maybe it's not Ubuntu specific but a Linux problem in general.

Comment: It depends on where you're saving them. Is it in the Windows system partition (unsafe and prone to the errors you're experiencing) or to a different NTFS partition (usually safe)?

Comment: Windows but why should it make any difference?

Comment: You shouldn't be writing to the Windows system partition from outside because Windows doesn't like it. It may detect changes and require error correction. It's not Ubuntu or Linux, it's a malpractice problem with Windows.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well I guess that makes sense. Strange that it does seem to work for individual files though. Anyway, lesson learnt. Save to /home next time. Thanks for your help.